# HTML5 video fully buffered but continuously send network request when seeking

Tags: html, video

When I fully buffered a mp4 file and seek, browser continuously sending network request and buffering (sometimes ~100ms simetimes 500ms depending on network). Someone knows why?

Even If I use a local file and seek, it also send Range request!

[image]

Comment: Give your code..to analyse the issue better

Comment: @3bu1 just dragging a mp4 file into browser, or simply use `<video src="test.mp4"></video>`and seek

Answer (score 1):

I think if you look at the request in detail you'll see the requests are cancelled (on Chrome anyway, which is what you are using above). See below for example (this happens when moving back along the timeline of a short video):

[image]

I suspect that the browser is simply making the request first as an optimisation and then cancelling it when it checks and confirms that it has the video already buffered.

You also should be able to see that the first request will have a range request from 0 onwards and the request when you move along the time bar have an offset reflecting where you moved to: